# Need Recommendations for Twitter and Facebook Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, twitter, oauth

I'm building an app in Rails 3. I currently have a user model which is authenticated via devise (email + password auth). I want to be able to show connect to facebook, connect to twitter buttons to the users once they are logged in.

After obtaining the keys from Facebook and Twitter, I'd want to store it in the database for future requests.

Which Ruby Gems should I be using for this use case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Facebooker, we just implemented a facebook-connect style login and application using [mini_fb](http://github.com/appoxy/mini_fb)

Mini_fb uses the new graph API, which is cool, and was easy to implement. We used Rails3 and authlogic, but difference to devise should be negligible.

For twitter, [this twitter gem](http://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter) is nice, but this [devise-twitter](http://github.com/MSch/devise-twitter) gem looks nice for login.

Comment: I just used devise-twitter. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, still no answers. Please check out the [Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/), I'm sure the answer is there. It will tell you what the most common gems are for your problem if you can figure out the categorization system. Also, [facebooker](http://facebooker.rubyforge.org/) is a nice gem but it's a little old.

Answer (score 1):

`Facebooker` is deprecated in favour of [`mogli`](http://github.com/mmangino/mogli), which uses the [Graph API](http://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=http%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fapi). And for Twitter, I'd recommend John Nunemaker's [`twitter`](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/). Since you are already using Devise, you can use the devise-twitter as mentioned by Jesse Wolgamott.